# Using the Range.End property to extend a multi-cell range

Tags: excel, vba

Using the below data, and recording the following actions in the Macro Recorder produces the below code:

```
Ctrl + C 
Ctrl + Shift + Right Arrow 
Ctrl + R
```

[image: Starting data with single-cell range selected]

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FillRight
End Sub
```

[image: Data after entering above keyboard strokes]

This is what I would expect. Performing exactly the same keyboard strokes when multiple cells are selected such as in the image below achieves the same result and produces the same code in the Macro Recorder. However, reusing this code does NOT produce that result when multiple cells are selected. Why does the Range.End property not work in this context i.e. extending a multi-cell range?

[image: Starting data with multi-cell range selected]

Comment: As it looks for a continuous range, which there isn't.

Comment: This is quite fun actually. I would go with a tiny bug/feature option.

Comment: You are copying, but not using what you've copied, you're only doing the fill right.  You want something like `resize` and `offset`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copyfill()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(REFERENCE)
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Cells(1,"B"),.Cells(1,LastCol).Value = .Cells(1,1).Value
End With
End Sub
```

Perhaps not an answer to your question, but this does the same. Hope it helps.

As Luuklag already mentioned, if you want to autofill a range, it has to be adjunct to a continuous range. Populate some continuous cells in `col A`, then add a value in `B1`. `Col B` will autofill without any problems. Try the same with only e.g. `A1` and `A20` populated, and you will notice `col B` does not autofill until the 20nd row.

Comment: There are lots of ways to achieve the desired result, but I'm trying to understand the discrepancy between the keyboard instructions and the code instructions. I don't understand why `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select` does not select the range from "A1" to "H1" in the case of the third screenshot above, and none of the responses so far have clarified this issue.

Comment: @STim - It does not select `A1:H1` in the third screenshot because you have a value in cell `B1`. The `End` method will only move to the end of the contiguous data range (up, down, left, right) from the point where it begins, or to the next cell with data if there is a blank cell directly after the starting cell.

Comment: Okay, I understand, the key issue is that the VBA range method measures from the left-most point (or beginning point) of the range. Clearly though, the keyboard shortcuts performed on the multi-cell range produce different instructions, which do not correspond to the code produced by the macro recorder.

Comment: It is very much possible that what the macro recorder produces is not the same as what goes on in the "brain" of excel/VBA. Regardless, I think it would not hurt if this issue were to be corrected in the next Excel update.

Answer (score 0):

**Get LASTROW**

Try this:

- Declare a range with the interval between ActiveCell for the last non-empty column;
- Use **for each** to enter all values ​​in each cell in the range.

  ```
  Public Sub copyLastColumn()
  Dim val As Variant: val = Selection.Value
  Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

  Dim rng As Range: Set rng = sh.Range(ActiveCell, _
                                   sh.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 
  sh.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, sh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))

  For Each el In rng
      el.Value = val
  Next el
  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This happened because commands in macro mean :

1. Selection = Range("A1")
2. Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Select

This mean "selection from cell A1 to the last cell in row 1 that contains data".

You have to make diffеrence between Selection from row 1 in macro - this is Range("A1") and selection, which you make with mouse, before to start macro !

That's why, when you select 2 neighbour cell with values in them, you think that macro do nothing - but macro do it's job - you can be convicted in this if you have diffеrent values in cells - for example Start in A1 and ST in A2 - after starting macro you will see that values in this cells became Start and Start

You can see this URL for more : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end

Comment: That's not correct. In the case of the data in the third diagram, the commands in the macro actually mean: `Range(Range("A1:B1"), Range("A1:B1").End(xlToRight))`. This is the same range reference as simply: `Range("A1:B1")`. Furthermore, `Range("A1:B1").End(xlToRight)` is equivalent to `Range("B1")`. So I can see why I'm getting the result I'm getting, but what I don't understand is why is there no correspondence between the keyboard shortcuts and the code produced?

Comment: No - when you record macro - in 1-st step you stay in call A1 - this is range A1. In macro , as first row, you have to add : Range("A1:H1").Select . Thus the range become A1:H1, not A1 . Then macro will behave as you wish. The problem was that at first step you have to select range A1:H1